# Using Both Query Api And Criteria Api in Hibernate Leads Problems

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

When I update a row with query API and then retrieve the data with criteria API in the same transaction, I get old value, not the updated value. Why is it like that and how can I solve the problem? I need to get the updated value.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService {
    @Autowired
    ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void example() {
        ExampleEntity entity = (ExampleEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ExampleEntity.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", 190001L)).uniqueResult();

        exampleRepository.updateState(190001L, State.CLOSED);

        ExampleEntity updatedEntity = (ExampleEntity)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ExampleEntity.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", 190001L)).uniqueResult();

        assertEquals(State.CLOSED, updatedEntity.getState());
    }

}

@Repository
public class ExampleRepositoryImpl implements ExampleRepository {
    public void updateState(Long id, State state) {
        String updateScript = "update exampleEntity set state= '%s', " +
                "VERSION = VERSION + 1 " +
                "where ID = %s;";

        updateScript = String.format(updateScript, state, id);

        Query sqlQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(updateScript);

        sqlQuery.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Note: If I delete the first line and don't retrieve entity at the beginning everything works as I expected.

Comment: How do you call both methods in the same transaction? Why don't execute them in different transactions?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I extremely simplified the code. In original version I have lots of executions and I want them to be atomic.

Comment: I would assume that it has somehting to do with caching, though I don't know much about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing native SQL and hibernate. Basically, when you first retrieve the entity, it gets stored in your session EntityManager. You then use plain SQL to update the row in the database, but as far as hibernate is concerned, the entity has not been dirtied because it isn't clever enough to understand how plain SQL relates to the object model. When you retrieve it the second time, it simply gives you the original entity it already has cached in the EntityManager rather than querying the database.

The solution is to simply manually force evict the entity from the EntityManager after the update as follows:
`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(entity);`

Or you could simply update the entity you fetched and persist it (best solution IMHO, no superfluous DAO method, and best abstraction away from the database):

```
ExampleEntity entity = (ExampleEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ExampleEntity.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", 190001L)).uniqueResult();

entity.setState(State.CLOSED);
entity.setVersion(e.getVersion() + 1);

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entity);
```

Basically... whichever option you choose, don't mix plain SQL and hibernate queries in the same transaction. Once hibernate has an object loaded, it will return that same entity from its cache until it knows for a fact that it is dirty. It is not clever enough to know that an entity is dirty when plain SQL was used to dirty it. If you have no choice and must use SQL (and this should never be the case in a well designed hibernate model), then call evict to tell hibernate the entity is dirty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed native SQL to HQL but I still get the old value. But the evict method works as expected and solved my problem. What could be wrong about HQL? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hmmm, I must admit you've made me second guess myself and consult the doc again. It would appear that a HQL update will manage invalidations in the L2 cache (application level), but not the L1 cache (session level). I guess the thinking is that you should be able to track invalidation as part of your business logic and should know to reuse an object you have already fetched rather than go back and get it again. I will update my answer accordingly.

My solution, don't use HQL updates. Get the entity from the container, manipulate it, and put it back into the container.

Comment: In addition to the answer sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().refresh(entity) usage can also be a good alternative to evict.

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction is still not committed when you get result - this is the reason you get "old" value.

Comment: in the same transaction I should get the updated value after update statement is executed. Indeed if I use only Query API or only Criteria API I get expected results. The problem is using both of them them in the same transaction. Also as I said, if I delete the first line I get the updated value.

Comment: Exactly what I said. Do not use them in same transaction, because transaction is not still commited. Reason why you get correct value when you use only Query API or Criteria API is that you do not get result from DB.

Comment: This is nothing to do with transactions. The entity is already loaded in the EntityManager and the plain SQL update does not cause then entity to be marked dirty. The second fetch just retrieved the cached entity and never goes to the database.